# Unable to create a text index in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am trying to create a text index in mongodb compass.

It gives me the following error:

```
Index build failed: 37ecddaa-47ae-4dc4-928e-2af83156fb10: Collection test.commerceProduct ( 9dc03ec5-cda1-4b61-8245-04d085846dbe ) :: caused by :: found language override field in document with non-string type
```

I am creating it on name field.

The values in name are not null neither empty, they are of string type.

If someone can please help.

Comment: Please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179664/error-when-using-a-text-index-on-mongodb

Comment: okay, great !!!

Comment: Hi, one more thing, There are five fields in my collection that I need to query for my application, three of them are strings and remaining two are list of strings. without indexing the query runs in 650ms. I am creating the text indexes on all five of fields (compound index) , the query optimiser in mongodb compass does not picks up this index for searching. The search type is of regex one. Also we cannot force it since it is of text type (regex). Lastly I created the sorted indexes on all fields individually, it works in about 1100 ms. I need it <500ms. Can you guide me on this ?

Comment: here is a bit of summary on it , I tried working with adding all text fields, the query selector does not uses them.
I have tried adding them individually, as a text field, again the query selector does not uses them.
Then I have tried adding them in regular manner (sorted), by adding all the fields individually, the query selector uses them, but the timing is about 1100 instead of 600.
Also we cannot force the query to use the created index for execution , as from docs “You cannot use hint() if the query includes a $text query expression.” @Alokp